# how to make a python program for doing a few tasks repeatedly for same number of times but each having independent time intervals?

Tags: python

Edit:
Thank you very much guys. This code is finally working:

```
# imports
from pynput.keyboard import Key,Controller
import time
import threading

keyboard = Controller()

a=int(input("Enter the number of loops to send: "))

arr=["pls beg","pls fish","pls hunt","pls postmemes","c","pls search","hospital", "pls highlow", "high", "pls trivia", "C", "pls deposit all"]

print("Please take the cursor where you want to spam the message, spamming will start in 5 seconds...")

time.sleep(5)
num=0

def doFunc(function, timeToSleep):
    for num in range(a):
        # we pass functions because the class is not initialised
        function(functions, timeToSleep)

# the function with classes
class functions:
    # example functions

    def function1(self, timeToSleep):    #pls beg command (cooldown of 30s)
        time.sleep(timeToSleep)
        keyboard.type(arr[0])
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)   
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)

    def function2(self, timeToSleep):    #pls fish command  (cooldown of 30s)
        time.sleep(timeToSleep)
        keyboard.type(arr[1])
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)

    def function3(self, timeToSleep):    #pls hunt command  (cooldown of 30s)
        time.sleep(timeToSleep)
        keyboard.type(arr[2])
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)

    def function4(self, timeToSleep):    #pls postmemes command  (cooldown of 30s)
        time.sleep(timeToSleep)
        keyboard.type(arr[3])
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        keyboard.type(arr[4])
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)

    def function5(self, timeToSleep):    #pls search command  (cooldown of 30s)
        time.sleep(timeToSleep)
        keyboard.type(arr[5])
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        keyboard.type(arr[6])
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)

    def function6(self, timeToSleep):    #pls highlow command  (cooldown of 20s)
        time.sleep(timeToSleep)
        keyboard.type(arr[7])
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        keyboard.type(arr[8])
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)

    def function7(self, timeToSleep):    #pls trivia command  (cooldown of 10s)
        time.sleep(timeToSleep)
        keyboard.type(arr[9])
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        keyboard.type(arr[10])
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)

    def function8(self, timeToSleep):    #pls deposit all command  (cooldown of 45s)
        time.sleep(timeToSleep)
        keyboard.type(arr[11])
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)


# change the times you want each function to sleep
timesDict = {
    functions.function1: 32,
    functions.function2: 31,
    functions.function3: 33,
    functions.function4: 34,
    functions.function5: 35,
    functions.function6: 21,
    functions.function7: 11,
    functions.function8: 45
}

# start threads
for f, t in timesDict.items(): threading.Thread(target=doFunc, args=(f, t)).start()
```

How can I make a python program for doing a few tasks repeatedly for same number of times (can use a simple for loop here) but each having independent time intervals? For example, I want function 1 to be executed every 30 seconds, function 2 to be executed every 17 seconds, function 3 to be executed every 36 seconds, and so on. I tried doing it using `time.sleep()`, but I  couldn't make it work since their time intervals are independent of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use threads

```py
# imports
import time
import threading

def doFunc(function, timeToSleep):
    while True:
        # we pass functions because the class is not initialised
        function(functions, timeToSleep)

# the function with classes
class functions:
    # example functions

    def function1(self, timeToSleep):
        time.sleep(timeToSleep)
        print('func 1 finished')

    def function2(self, timeToSleep):
        time.sleep(timeToSleep)
        print('func 2 finished')


# change the times you want each function to sleep
timesDict = {
    functions.function1: 5,
    functions.function2: 1
}

# start threads
for f, t in timesDict.items(): threading.Thread(target=doFunc, args=(f, t)).start()

# output
>>> 'func 2 finished'
>>> 'func 2 finished'
>>> 'func 2 finished'
>>> 'func 2 finished'
>>> 'func 1 finished'
# if i understood the question correctly, this is what you want
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [blogpost](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/). I think you have to use threading and multiprocessing for your case.This basically creates child process to run your function independently.

OR
You can try this one

```py
    def function():   #pls beg command (cooldown of 30s)
      keyboard.type(arr[0])
      keyboard.press(Key.enter)
      keyboard.release(Key.enter)
      return 1 #You return your function

    # then in main function inside the loop use this
     if function():
        time.sleep('30 secs')
```

Answer (score 0):

Create for every function a variable like last_running last_running_2 ect...
And you check every time `if time.time()-last_running >= 30` then 30 seconds have passed and you can run the function.
it will look like this:

```
while True:
    if time.time()-last_running >= 30:
        last_running = time.time() #you update the last running every time
        function()
    if time.time()-last_running_2 >= 17:
        last_running_2 = time.time()
        function(2)
```

Comment: thanks for the response but I am sorry to inform you that I tried it but it didnt work. Is there any library required to use this?

Comment: Please check the question again if possible. I have uploaded the code which I wrote based with the help of your comment, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: time libarary so you do import time